# python 3.4 sub process

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-3.4

I am trying to control subprocess and control the stdout and stdin of this process.
It worked great with python 2.7 but when using python 3 it fails to run.

I wrote the following code in python 2.7:

```
print("python 2.7:\n")
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat -'],
                        shell = True,
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        #stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
for i in range(10):
    proc.stdin.write('%d\n' % i)
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    print (output.rstrip())

remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
remainder = remainder.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("'","").split(",")[0]
print("-----------------")
print(remainder)
```

as I said, this code works fine, but when trying to write it in python 3.4 I fail to use the stdin.write properly.

```
print("python 3.4:\n")
proc = subprocess.Popen(['cat -'],
                        shell = True,
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                        universal_newlines = True

                        )

for i in range(10):
    inp = str(i)
    proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdout.flush()
    proc.stdin.write(inp)

    output = proc.stdout.read()
    print (output.rstrip())

remainder = proc.communicate()[0]
remainder = remainder.replace("(","").replace(")","").replace("'","").split(",")[0]
print("-----------------")
print(remainder)
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, `output = proc.stdout.read()` will block reading the file until EOF which is likely when the process exits. The second round of your loop, if you get there at all, will not succeed.

Comment: Your process may behave differently if its stdin is a pipe instead of a terminal. The `pexpect` module on unixy systems can come in handy in that case.

Comment: @tdelaney: python 2.7 code works and therefore there is no need to use `pexpect` here. Though in general, [`pexpect` may be useful](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost there. It is a buffering problem:

- `bufsize=0` (unbuffered) on Python 2.7 by default
- `bufsize=-1` (fully buffered)  on Python 3.4 (the default has been changed)

You should put `proc.stdin.flush()` *after* `proc.stdin.write()` (before the `.write()` call, the buffer is empty -- there is nothing to flush):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(['cat'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1,
           universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, file=process.stdin, flush=True)
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        print(output, end='')
```

It is a complete code example.

Note: in general, unless the you know **exactly** how much you need to read (like in the example: one line input -> one line output exactly); the input/output might become desynchronized and the deadlock might happen e.g., if the child produces less output than you expect then your process will block on `.readline()` while the child at the same time hangs awaiting for input from you. A more robust solution would work with child process' streams asynchronously (asyncio, threading, select).